# Getting error OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x051D937C through pytest for python-C++ mixed mode application

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am running a shell script which runs all test cases in python using pytest for application written in python and C++. DLL is used for integration with python code. We have used ctypes ( CDLL) interface of python to call C++ methods from python code. Problem is when I run same test case individually it run without any error but when I ran through automation ( using shell script) it throws following error at code location in python file

```
    c_length_ = ctypes.c_uint(len(c_data))
    c_data_p_ = ctypes.c_char_p(c_data)
    is_last_ = ctypes.c_bool(last_in_block)
    dec_length = ctypes.c_uint()
    dec_data_p = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8)()
    no_data = ctypes.c_bool()
    self._vlib_api.dec_data(c_length_, **<-- line error is pointed**
                            c_data_p_,
                            is_last_,
                            ctypes.byref(dec_length),
                            ctypes.byref(dec_data_p),
                            ctypes.byref(no_data))
```

**E       OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x051D937C**

**C++ method is as follows** :

```
         __declspec(dllexport) void VLibDecData(const uint32_t c_length,
                              const uint8_t* c_data_p,
                              const bool is_last_,
                              uint32_t& dec_length,
                              uint8_t*& dec_data_p,
                              bool& no_data)
```

So question is how do I fix it and what is wrong in above call to C++ API ?
Hope to get an answer here

Comment: Without seeing at least the function prototype we can't tell if you are calling the API correctly.  Note that `ctypes` is for calling C functions, not C++, so you at least need to make sure the C++ functions are wrapped in `extern "C" {}` and only use POD types.  The first two lines of your code look suspicious.  `c_data` is wrapped in both `c_uint` and `c_char_p`.  Which is it?  Looks like it should be `c_uint(len(c_data))`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen : My bad, I forgot to mention len(c_data) in argument. I have edit the question with correction and also provided C++ side function which is being called. All other methods works fine but only this method is throwing error when run in automation.

Comment: That all looks fine, although I recommend using `.argtypes` and `.restype` instead of wrapping parameters individually for each call.   My guess is since it works alone is that another API has a buffer overflow or some such causing undefined behavior that affects the call.

Comment: @MarkTolonen You seem to be right ! It is something else causing this issue. I am trying to check how to debug it using Visual Studio 2019. Any clue how to debug such issues ? Would WinDbg help ?

Comment: In VS, if you can locate data corruption and it is repeatable, you can set a data breakpoint to watch for changes before the corruption occurs, then it will break on the code that corrupts it. Building a debug version can help locate buffer overflows when they happen as well.